# Sqlite update command is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

When i try to update a table its giving me a

> error message : near "(": syntax error

Please anybody suggest me to rectify this issue.

I am updating a table when i click the save button (Bar button item) on the tool bar which is placed below.

The problem is it's always going to else statement of `sqlite3_step`.

I am not getting whats the exact problem for this issue and the above mentioned error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Following is my update method :

```
   if ([databaseManager didExistDatabaseInDocumentDirectory] == YES)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [[databaseManager getDatabasePathFromDocument] UTF8String];

        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &scanningDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *update_stmt1 = "UPDATE FILES SET (documentType,orderNumber) VALUES (?,?) WHERE ID = ?";
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(scanningDB, update_stmt1, -1, &stmt, NULL);

            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [str1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3,[num intValue]);

            if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                sqlite3_reset(stmt);
                NSLog(@"Record Updated Successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Could not Update Record");
                NSLog(@" error message %s",sqlite3_errmsg(scanningDB));
                sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
                sqlite3_close(scanningDB);
                return NO;
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            sqlite3_close(scanningDB);

        }
        else
            return NO;
    }
    else
        return NO;
```

Comment: it looks like your update query is wrong. Check out here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your query with the following.

```
const char *update_stmt1 = "UPDATE FILES SET documentType = ? ,orderNumber = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: But i just want to know why this is not working : UPDATE FILES SET (documentType,orderNumber) VALUES (?,?) WHERE ID = ?. i have used same syntax for inserting, there its working fine.

Comment: @NagendraK In Insert It was worked but sqlite may be not support same syntax for UPDATE. If this helps you. you can tick this as answer.

Comment: Ok thanks.Ya I have already ticked it. But since i don't have 15 reputation as for now it is not showing to public.

Comment: @NagendraK as you post then question. Only you can accept the answer. to accept answer there is one tick mark showing at left side of my answer. If you find any problem please let me know so I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is wrong.

```
UPDATE FILES SET (documentType,orderNumber) VALUES (?,?) WHERE ID = ?
```

**Syntax:**

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

**Your query:**

```
UPDATE FILES SET documentType =?, orderNumber =? where ID =?, documentTypeString, Yourordernumber, yourID
```

**Sample:**

```
   - (void) update
        {
            if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if(updateStatement == nil)
                {
                    const char *sql = "UPDATE FILES SET documentType =?, orderNumber =? where ID =?";
                    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, & updateStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }

               sqlite3_bind_text(documentType
, 1, [comment UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(orderNumber
, 2, [categoria UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(ID, 3, id);


                if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStatement))
                    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                else
                    //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
                    //noteID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

                    //Reset the update statement.
                    sqlite3_reset(updateStatement);
                sqlite3_close(database);
                deleteStatement = nil;
            }
            else
                sqlite3_close(database);
        }
```

**Basic SQLite tutorial:**
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/index.htm

Comment: You mean to say it should be like this  :const char *update_stmt1 = "UPDATE FILES SET documentType = ?, orderNumber = ? WHERE ID = ?";

Comment: OR should it be like this : const char *update_stmt1 = "UPDATE FILES SET documentType = [str UTF8String], orderNumber = [str1 UTF8String] WHERE ID = [num intValue]";

Comment: Thank you Ramesh_T.It worked fro me. const char *update_stmt1 = "UPDATE FILES SET documentType = ?, orderNumber = ? WHERE ID = ?";

Comment: Can you upvote and accept the answer? This will help others

Comment: Ya.I have already voted. But since i don't have 15 reputation as for now it is not showing to public.

Comment: Can you please tell me why this is not working : UPDATE FILES SET (documentType,orderNumber) VALUES (?,?) WHERE ID = ?. i have used same syntax for inserting, there its working fine.